# Migrating column definition LONG to CLOB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

We have a table which is having a LONG datatype column. A procedure is used (from front end application) to insert data into this table which is also having input parameter as LONG.

Now due to some issues with LONG column values we need to switch from LONG TO CLOB. This needs to be performed on production database.

**Sample :**

Table Name : TEST_REC_TAB

[image]

this table is containing approx millions of records.

Can I proceed with the below steps.

1. Create a new table using below. Now LONG column will be created as CLOB in new table.

   `create table TEST_REC_TAB_BKP as select E_ID ,to_lob(EMAIL_BODY) EMAIL_BODY from TEST_REC_TAB;`
2. Rename the TEST_REC_TAB table to some different name.

   `alter table TEST_REC_TAB RENAME TO TEST_REC_TAB_TEMP;`
3. Rename backup table to original. (to use bkp table as original table)

   `alter table TEST_REC_TAB_BKP RENAME TO TEST_REC_TAB;`
4. Set CLOB column in new table as not null;

   `alter table TEST_REC_TAB modify email_body not null;`

new table as below

[image]

Further we will change the below highlighted LONG parameter to CLOB in procedure.

[image]

Will there be any issue with this approach? Kindly suggest if there is any better way to achieve this.

OR

Can we directly alter the main table column from LONG to CLOB?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/migrating-columns-from-LONGs-to-LOBs.html#GUID-8636A7D5-1149-40F9-A705-3903B5155D9B) shows several techniques to migrate, including a direct alter (which essentially does these steps for you in the background).

Comment: If the procedure currently works fine with a PL/SQL LONG parameter, you probably don’t need to change it. PL/SQL LONG is just varchar2 32k, so as a procedure parameter it’s the same thing as varchar2.

Comment: As Alex said, there are several methods for doing this in the Oracle docs. If you wanted to do it programmatically, you can use PL/SQL to assign a fetched LONG value to a CLOB variable - PL/SQL does the conversion work under the covers on assignment. Once it's in a CLOB, you can write that to your new table. But look at the docs for other options first.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done directly, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( x int, y long );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  values (1,'xxx');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter table t modify y clob;

Table altered.
```

but its an expensive operation and could mean an extended time that the table is out of commission.  Check out DBMS_REDEFINITION as a nice way of basically automating the process you described above, whilst keeping access to the table during 99% of the exercise.